# Deleting a record from a database in HTML5

Tags: database, html, indexeddb, delete-row

Using HTML5 code, I'm unable to delete from the database even though the onsuccess event is triggered.My delete code is as below:

```
btnDelete.addEventListener("click", function(){
        //alert("At Delete function");
        var AadharNumber = document.getElementById("AadharNumber").value;
        var transaction = db.transaction("CustDetails",IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
        var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("CustDetails");
        var request = objectStore.delete(AadharNumber);
        request.onsuccess = function(event){
            alert( "Aadhar Number: "+ AadharNumber + " deleted from the database");
        };

    },false);
```

Then when i click the print button after the delete, i still get to see the same records.Below is my print function.

```
btnPrint.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    var output = document.getElementById("printOutput");
                    output.textContent = "";
                    var transaction = db.transaction("CustDetails", IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
                    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("CustDetails");

                    var request = objectStore.openCursor();
                    request.onsuccess = function(event) {  
                        var cursor = event.target.result;  
                        if (cursor) {  
                            output.textContent += "<li>""Aadhar Number: " + cursor.key + " is " + cursor.value.name + "</li>";
                            cursor.continue();  

                        }  
                        else {  
                            console.log("No more entries!");  
                        }  
                    };  
                }, false);
```

My html code is as below:

```
<body><center>
<div id="container">
    <label for="txtName">
    Name:
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" />
    <br />
    <label for="txtEmail">
    Email:
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" />
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Record" />
    <br />
    <label for="AadharNumber">
    ID:
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="AadharNumber" name="txtAadharNumber" />
    <input type="button" id="btnDelete" value="Delete Record" />
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="btnPrint" value="Print Records" />
    <br />
    <output id="printOutput" > </output>
</div>  
</center>
</body>
```

What is wrong with my delete? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The code seems fine however you could check if converting the string key to integer value helps deleting the object from the object store.

```
var AadharNumber =  parseInt(document.getElementById("AadharNumber").value);
```

Comment: Also, is there any way i can insert a new line like "/n" after "output.textContent" in "if(cursor)" condition in print function?

Comment: yes just add the line break html tag at the end of the line <br/>